decommissioning data nodes in hdfs
I have some data nodes in Apache hdfs with replication factor 1 and want to decommission some of them and don't want to loss data which stored in them.
because of volume of data, can't download data on local machine and upload them to other live nodes.
only solution I have is to set rep factor to 2, but it takes too much times.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

You need not to do anything manually HDFS will handle replicating those blocks else where itself
From the official Apache Doc:
When an administrator decommission a datanode, the datanode will first be transitioned into DECOMMISSION_INPROGRESS state. After all blocks belonging to that datanode have been fully replicated elsewhere based on each block’s replication factor. the datanode will be transitioned to DECOMMISSIONED state. After that, the administrator can shutdown the node to perform long-term repair and maintenance that could take days or weeks. After the machine has been repaired, the machine can be recommissioned back to the cluster.
https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/HdfsDataNodeAdminGuide.html
